# How to configure Sonarqube with Jenkins and Perforce

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube, perforce

How do I implement Sonarqube with Jenkins and Perforce,I have configured Sonarqube in our server and our source code is in Perforce,I know we can install perforce plugin in Sonarqube,so if I configure perforce plugin in Sonarqube ,will it fetch the latest code from perforce and analyse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonarQube will not fetch source code by itself. You have to configure Jenkins to do that (there is a [Jenkins plugin for Perforce](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Perforce+Plugin)).

Once your Jenkins job properly fetch source code, you can run a SonarQube analysis using a [SonarQube Scanner step](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzingwiththeSonarQubeScanner).

You should now have your source code properly analyzed and browsable in SonarQube.

On top of that you can install and configure the [SonarQube Perforce plugin](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-scm-perforce) that will collect blame of all analyzed files and then allow to automatically assign issues to the last committer (but that's not mandatory).

Comment: Thanks for your immediate help @Julien, I have one more doubt,you mentioned that ,Jenkins job will fetch the code, so is that mean do we need to fetch the code to SonarQube server? or is anyway we can run the SonarQube scanner step for the code in a remote location.

Comment: Jenkins works with its own workspace. The Jenkins Perforce plugin will fetch the code in Jenkins workspace. then you can run any tool on that code (compile, test, sonarqube, ...). The SonarQube Scanner will analyze files present in the Jenkins workspace (so here there is no relation with Perforce) and push analysis result (including source code) to the SonarQube server.